# Semantic approach: horizontal navigations tabs aka liteaccordion

Tags: javascript, html, dom, semantics

I try to make semantic site based on that concept:
I have normal nav:

```
<nav>
 <ul>
  <li><a/></li>
  ...
  <li><a/></li>
</nav>
```

And content in tabs which work together as same as in liteaccordion.

How it works in litecordion(**#2**):
Content have to be inside `<li>` but it's not valid. So the pure HTML, before js start has normal:

```
<div class="content"/>
...
<div class="content"/>
<nav/>
```

structure. On load, JS move every content to the right li tab:

```
<nav>
 <ul>
  <li class="foo content">
   <a/>
   <div class="foo content"/>
  </li>
  ...
  <li class="bar content">
   <a/>
   <div class="bar content"/>
  </li>
</nav>
```

And then litecordion starts...

But I made some piece of job (**#1** on image) to make it 100% semantic even after JS manipulation. Navigation in there is just on another layer than content div. It detects actual position of tab and set position of appropriate content. But there's a lot of events to calculate.

[image]

[Live example](http://jsfiddle.net/respown/UgUaE/), It's complicated and slow and buggy.

So I'm asking is it worth time to create semantic separate navigation and content for users with JS? Do I need to detect some search bots etc. ? The example will use ajax, but for persons/bots without js it will be full semantic.